# Django: Multiple bulk create within a transaction

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to do multiple bulk creates(independent) within a transaction.

```
            with transaction.atomic():
                if x:
                   X.objects.bulk_create(x_objs)
                if y:
                    Y.objects.bulk_create(y_objs)
                if z:
                    Z.objects.bulk_create(z_objs)
```

Now I want X to rollback if Y or Z fails. How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Normally the transaction should already get rolled back if an exception is happening inside the [`transaction.atomic()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) block.

If you need to [rollback](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.rollback) for a more complex use case you can do it manually:

```
        with transaction.atomic():
            if x:
               X.objects.bulk_create(x_objs)
            try:
                if y:
                    Y.objects.bulk_create(y_objs)
                if z:
                    Z.objects.bulk_create(z_objs)
            except Exception: # Your exception
                transaction.rollback()
```

Though normally you shouldnt catch exceptions yourself in an `atomic()` block as then it wouldn't work as intended.

> When exiting an atomic block, Django looks at whether it’s exited normally or with an exception to determine whether to commit or roll back. If you catch and handle exceptions inside an atomic block, you may hide from Django the fact that a problem has happened. This can result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: within an active transaction block?